# Getting String before numbers with regexp in java

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to get first part of a String before 4 numbers in ().

```
Input String: "Some Title (2000) some text."
Output String: "Some Title "
```

I don't want to iterate over matches and get first. I want regex to get the characters before 4 numbers in () and I want it to discard the rest of the text.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show your attempts? Or are the SO community just going to do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Regexp would be something like

```
(.*)\(\d{4}\).*
```

For usage in Java you need to escape backshlashes and the output string is at group 1.

Answer (score 1):

For exactly this type of text:

```
String result = input.split("\\(")[0];
```

or, if `(` may occur in the first part:

```
String result = input.split("\\(\\d{4}\\)")[0];
```

This even works for inputs containing no number at all and empty strings.